# Merge multiple data frame

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("A","B","C"), f1 = c(1,2,3), f2 = c("zz","mo","do"))
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("D","B","C"), f1 = c(1,4,6), f2 = c("ok","no","do"))
df3 <- data.frame(name = c("D","E","C"), f1 = c(1,2,3), f2 = c("so","yo","kl"))
```

I want to merge them into one data frame, so that it looks like

```
name    df.1f1   df1.f2    df2.f1   df2.f2   df3.f1   df3.f2
A            1       zz        na       na       na       na     
B            2       mo         4       no       na       na      
C            3       do         6       do        3       kl
D           na       na         1       ok        1       so
E           na       na        na       na        2       yo
```

Although I can use repeated dplyr::full_join to do this but it is too tedious. Anyone have a better way to do this?

Comment: Look at the `Reduce` function, and search SO for combinations of `Reduce` and `merge`.

Comment: Also, it's `data.frame`, not `dataframe`.

Comment: Also, consider `rbindlist` + `dcast` from "data.table".

Answer (score 15):

In case you have multiple dataframes you can make a list of them.
Inspired by [vaettchen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976470/vaettchen)

```
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="name",all=TRUE) ,list(df1,df2,df3))
```

Answer (score 6):

As always in `R`, there a lot of ways. For me, a nested merge would do the job well enough:

```
merge( merge( df1, df2, by = "name", all = TRUE ), df3, by = "name", all = TRUE )

  name f1.x f2.x f1.y f2.y f1   f2
1    A    1   zz   NA <NA> NA <NA>
2    B    2   mo    4   no NA <NA>
3    C    3   do    6   do  3   kl
4    D   NA <NA>    1   ok  1   so
5    E   NA <NA>   NA <NA>  2   yo
```